# Facebook Graph API not return email and id properly (06/01/2018)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm using graph api FB.init with 

**config:** 

cookie : true, xfbml : true, version : 'v2.11'

**prmision:**
email,user_hometown,user_religion_politics,publish_actions,user_likes,user_status,user_about_me,user_location,user_tagged_places,user_birthday,user_photos,user_videos,user_education_history,user_posts,user_website,user_friends,user_relationship_details,user_work_history,user_games_activity,user_relationships

```
FB.api("/me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,email&limit=100", function(response){
        if(response && !response.error){
            console.log(response);
        }
});
```

But the outpus just like this:
[MyOutputGraphAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHZxq.png)

why id and email did not show up properly


Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

`taggable_friends` is for tagging only, so you just get the name and a tagging token. You can only get the email of a user if that user authorized your App. You cannot get the email of friends if they did not authorize your App.

The API call: `/me/friends?fields=id,name,email`

Again, this only returns emails of friends who authorized your App with the email permission. There is no other way to get emails, you would not even be allowed to store the emails without the permission of each single user anyway.

Comment: what is another way to get email?

Comment: `You use /me/friends?fields=id,name,email` and you will get email for all friends that granted `user_friends` and `user_email` permission to the app.